# suppress rows in MS Access (related to Concatenating multiple rows into single line in MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, rows

I currently have a table that looks like the following:

**Name** --- **Cat** --- **Desc** --- **Thresh** --- **Perc** --- **Err** --- **BP** --- **Date**

Bob -------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05------0-----ADC2--12/02/2011
Bob -------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05------2-----BAC2--09/05/2011
Bob -------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05------0-----RBE2--11/02/2011
Bob -------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05------8-----VBE2--08/14/2012
Bob -------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05------6-----AEC2--02/25/2009
Bob -------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05------0-----PBC2--07/02/2011
Bob -------C2-------Com------8Per--------0.45------1-----XBC4--09/05/2011
Bob -------C2-------Com------8Per--------0.45------0-----AEC2--02/02/2010
Bob -------C2-------Com------8Per--------0.45------0-----PBC2--08/14/2012
Bob -------C2-------Com------8Per--------0.45------3-----ADC2--05/05/2001
Bob -------C2-------Com------8Per--------0.45------0-----ADC2--08/02/2010
Bob -------C2-------Com------8Per--------0.45------0-----BAC2--06/17/2010
Joe--------C1-------Inf---------7Per--------0.05------0-----PBC2--08/14/2012
Joe--------C1-------Inf---------7Per--------0.05------0-----ZTM2--09/05/2011
Joe--------C1-------Inf---------7Per--------0.05------2-----QYC2--05/17/2010
Joe--------C1-------Inf---------7Per--------0.05------0-----FLC2--3/19/2010
Joe--------C1-------Inf---------7Per--------0.05------1-----KSC2--09/05/2011
Joe--------C1-------Inf---------7Per--------0.05------0-----JYC2--08/14/2012

Let's say I wanted to build a query to say something like: show me all records still within this same format:

**Name** --- **Cat** --- **Desc** --- **Thresh** --- **Perc** --- **Err** --- **BP**
Bob -------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05-----16-----BAC2, VBE2, AEC2
Bob -------C2------Com------8Per--------0.45------4------XBC4, ADC2
Joe--------C1-------Inf--------7Per--------0.05------3------QYC2, KSC2

**But** for a date range of 01/01/2009 to 09/31/2011

I have used the function created by 
http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html Allen Browne in conjunction with the following SQL

```
SELECT
    [Name],
    [Cat],
    [Desc],
    [Thresh],
    [Perc],
    sum([Err]),
    ConcatRelated("[BP]", "make_table_bp", "[Err] = " & [BP])
FROM make_table_bp
GROUP BY
    [Name],
    [Cat],
    [Desc],
    [Thresh],
    [Perc],
    [Err],
    [BP];
```

But now i want to incorporate the date range into the SQL and still have distinct records based on this date range. Is this even possible?

Say the query was the following:

```
SELECT
    sub.[Name],
    sub.Cat,
    sub.[Desc],
    sub.Thresh,
    sub.Perc,
    sub.SumOfErr,
    ConcatRelated("BP",
        "make_table_bp",
        "[Err] > 0 AND [Name] = '" & sub.[Name]
        & "' AND Cat = '"
        & sub.Cat & "'",
        "BP")
        AS concat_BP
FROM
    (SELECT
        q.[Name],
        q.Cat,
        q.[Desc],
        q.Thresh,
        q.Perc,
        Sum(q.[Err]) AS SumOfErr
    FROM make_table_bp AS q
    GROUP BY
        q.[Name],
        q.Cat,
        q.[Desc],
        q.Thresh,
        q.Perc
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY
    sub.Name,
    sub.Cat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a WHERE clause to limit the range of [Date] values.  You will also need to do the same for the third argument to the ConcatRelated function.  (That third argument serves the same purpose as a WHERE clause in a query.)

In the main query:

```
FROM make_table_bp
WHERE [Date] >= #01/01/2009# AND [Date] <= #09/30/2011#
GROUP BY
```

And for the function:

```
ConcatRelated("[BP]", "make_table_bp", "[Err] = " & [BP]
   & " AND [Date] >= #01/01/2009# AND [Date] <= #09/30/2011#")
```

This suggestion is based on two assumptions.

1. The example query in your question does what you want except for limiting the results by [Date] range.
2. The [Date] field is Date/Time data type.

**Edit**:  Just saw the latest query version in your updated question.  I suspected that was coming.  So try this:

```
SELECT
    sub.[Name],
    sub.Cat,
    sub.[Desc],
    sub.Thresh,
    sub.Perc,
    sub.SumOfErr,
    ConcatRelated("BP",
        "make_table_bp",
        "[Err] > 0 AND [Name] = '" & sub.[Name]
        & "' AND Cat = '"
        & sub.Cat
        & "' AND [Date] >= #01/01/2009# AND [Date] <= #09/30/2011#",
        "BP")
        AS concat_BP
FROM
    (SELECT
        q.[Name],
        q.Cat,
        q.[Desc],
        q.Thresh,
        q.Perc,
        Sum(q.[Err]) AS SumOfErr
    FROM make_table_bp AS q
    WHERE [Date] >= #01/01/2009# AND [Date] <= #09/30/2011#
    GROUP BY
        q.[Name],
        q.Cat,
        q.[Desc],
        q.Thresh,
        q.Perc
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY
    sub.Name,
    sub.Cat;
```

Comment: when i execute the above query, i get an error: "Syntax error in date in query expression '[Date] >= #01/01/2009# AND [Date] <= #09/31/2011#.' Is the the "#" a date data type?

Comment: The # character is the delimiter for Date/Time literal values.  What is the data type of your [Date] field in the make_table_bp table?  Is it Date/Time or text?

Comment: I'm stumped then.  Date is a reserved word, but you have it surrounded by square brackets, so that *should* avoid confusing the db engine.   I don't understand why you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: I noticed that if i take away the second "AND" reference to the date in both the WHERE clause and the "ConcatRelated", it seems to work fine. So if i simply say [Date] >= #01/01/2009#...theres no problem. That doesnt make sense to me!

Comment: Another answer, now deleted, pointed out that #09/31/2011# is not a valid date.  I changed this answer to use #09/30/2011# instead.